# jQuery infinite thumbnail gallery

Tags: jquery, thumbnails, carousel, image-gallery, infinite-scroll

I am searching for a jQuery plugin to make gallery like this one made in Flash:

http://flash.tutfactory.com/interface/infinite-sliding-gallery/

I've queried Google for 'jquery infinite gallery', 'jquery scrolling gallery' etc., but could not find anything similar. All it returned was infinite scrolling galleries loaded by Ajax when you scroll down the page. Do you know any plugin implementing such functionality? Free or premium it doesn't matter for me. Funny I found this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13874677/looking-for-jquery-infinite-carousel-with-mouseover-activation with similar question, it was closed few days ago, I hope mine won't. The closest thing I found made in jQuery is this: 
http://manos.malihu.gr/tuts/jquery_thumbnail_scroller_horizontal_full_light.html#
but I can't find out how to implement various scrolling speeds depending on how close to the edge the mouse is, and how to make it loop smoothly.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: To mimic that exact Flash look-&-feel in jQuery you'll likely have to build the plugin yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to increase or decrease the speed of the scroll, you can create a transparent div, that will sit on the place you want the mouse to hover. Then run a function:

```
$("div").mouseover(function(){
    //increase here your speed
}).mouseout(function(){
    //decrease here your speed
});
```

Here you have a tutorial how to write an infinite carousel gallery:
http://www.queness.com/resources/html/carousel/index.html

Comment: Thank you for reply, I found that tutorial too, forgot to mention it. The thing is, on that tut they change the image on click or after some time, in my slider i would like it to happen on hover, and I can't imagine when should i load the first, second and so on item after the last one. I am not very experienced and it looks very hard for me, but if there is no such plugin I'll try to write it myself. Thanks again.

Comment: Good luck, it's a good start point to become a programmer and not a "copy-paster" :)

Answer (score 0):

As far as using the mouse to control scrolling, here is some code pulled from a site I did that has the mouse scrolling, but it is for a specific size gallery - not infinite.  As adamb said in the comment, you'll probably have to build it yourself, but this can act as some started code to detect the mouse location.  Basically you'll have to just create the illusion on infinity by moving images as they scroll out of view.  If they scroll left side, move the images to the right as they scroll and vice-versa.

```
            $(function() {
buildThumbs();

function buildThumbs() {
    $('div.portfolio_gallery').each(function() {
        var width = 0;

        var wrapper = $(this).find('.gallery'); 
        wrapper.find('.scroller a').each( function() {
            width += $('.single_img').outerWidth(true);
        });

        var thumbs = $(this).find('.scroller');
        thumbs.css('width', width + 'px');

        makeScrollable(thumbs, wrapper);
    });
}
   function makeScrollable(thumbs, wrapper) {
    var width = wrapper.innerWidth();

    wrapper.scrollLeft(0);

    var leftBuffer = 100;
    var rightBuffer = 100;

    //When user move mouse over menu
    wrapper.unbind('mousemove').bind('mousemove', function(e) {
        var xPos = e.pageX - wrapper.offset().left - leftBuffer;
        var xMax = wrapper.innerWidth() - rightBuffer;
        if(xPos > 0 && xPos < xMax) {
            var perc = xPos / (xMax - leftBuffer);
            var scrollAmt = thumbs.outerWidth(true) - wrapper.innerWidth();
            wrapper.scrollLeft(perc * scrollAmt);
        }
    });
   }
 });
```

Comment: I'll give it a try, with your code I have a starting point so it should be easier. Thank you.

Comment: @user1913951 great! let me know how it goes or if you need any more guidance